# Use variable to append field parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, append, ado

Cross Posted Here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?696163-Use-variable-to-append-field-parameter&p=4264077#post4264077

I am using ADO to retrieve data from MS Access into Excel, and I want to append an Iif statement into the SELECT part of my query. My SQL string is stored in a text file, and any parameters are being appended via ADO.

I know how to append parameters in the WHERE clause, and can even append parameters in the SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT BA, Iif(QA=[@somestring],[@somestring2], [@somestring3])
FROM myData
WHERE BA = 'some person'
```

But what I am trying to accomplish is to transform a placeholder [@somestring] into a variable length Iif statement, such as:

```
SELECT BA, [@somestring]
```

And the placeholder translates to a string I have built using a function:

```
Iif(QA='Jon Doe', 'Jon', Iif(QA='Jane Doe', 'Jane', 'Nobody')).
```

Right now, the result I get is the literal string I pass to the parameter populating the entire field.  So the Iif statement is literally written out for each record, rather than being evaluated by SQL.

Is what I am trying to do even possible, or does SQL need the Field for the Iif statement predefined in the initial command?

ie, Iif(QA=[@somestring], [@sometstring2], [@somestring3])

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight cut-and-paste from VBForums. It is a community wiki and only intended to remove this question from "no answers". It can be deleted or amended as appropriate.

---

FROM: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?696163-Use-variable-to-append-field-parameter&p=4264077#post4264077

BY: si_the_geek

> It isn't possible, you can only use parameters to set Values, you
>   can't do other things with them (such as field/table names, functions,
>   etc).
>
> If you want to alter the other parts of the query, you'll need to use
>   other methods (such as string building). In the example at the end of
>   your post, you should add that to the query string, and add the values
>   via parameters.